# How to get file size in byte using wc -c

Tags: linux, bash, wc

when I use the command to get the file size in bye using `wc -c` the command return two values, the size in byte and the file name, ex:
the output for `wc -c my_file` is `322 my_file`
I need to get only the first value to use it `if` condition, and I need to use this specific command not any other one..
Any help please, thank you.

Comment: `ls -s my_file | cut -d ' ' -f 1` could be faster especially for large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect stdin and `wc` wont know or echo the file name

```
wc -c < my_file
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done without redirection or wastefully reading the whole file using `stat`:

```
stat -c %s my_file
```